# Correct use of np.reshape() command

Tags: python, arrays, 2d, reshape

I have a 1D-array which has the following structure:

```
arr = [x,a,b,c,y,a,b,c]
```

How can I convert that 1D array into a 3D-array like this:

`arr2 = [[[x,a],[x,b],[x,c]], [[y,a], [y,b], [y,c]]]`
(3 y-values for each x-value)

Comment: You just changed the entire question (and the result is a 3D array, not 2D)

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
arr = np.array([1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6])

arr = arr.reshape((3, -1))
arr = np.delete(arr, 0, 1)
print(arr)
```

Result:

```
[[2 2 2]
 [4 4 4]
 [6 6 6]]
```

---

**After the OP's edit**, this is the answer

```python
arr = np.array([0, 7, 8, 9, 1, 7, 8, 9])

# Extract the component subarrays
sub_arr1 = arr[0:-1:4]   # every 4th element of arr
sub_arr2 = arr[1:4]      # the next 3 elements of arr, after skipping the first

m = np.array(np.meshgrid(sub_arr1, sub_arr2)).T
print(m)
```

Result:

```
[[[0 7]
  [0 8]
  [0 9]]

 [[1 7]
  [1 8]
  [1 9]]]
```

Comment: @brix consider accepting it as the solution if it solved your problem

Answer (score -1):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
arr = np.array(arr)
arr = arr.reshape(3,3)
print (list(arr))
```

Comment: that produces a 3x3 matrix, but **not** the output OP desires. read carefully. please take the [tour]

Comment: His question was edited, always keep it in mind

Comment: OP's question, before the edit, looked to me like they wanted to slice off a column of the reshaped array. you answered neither version of OP's question, as far as I can see.